# Why app sometimes crashes when getting Icon from file?

Tags: c++, windows, trayicon

I have functions to load and get Icon from files as follows:

```
std::map<wstring, HICON> m_map_icons;

void WindowSysTray::_loadIconFromFiles()
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        wstring temp = path + trayList[i];
        HICON hIcon = NULL;
        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(temp.c_str(), false);
        bitmap.GetHICON(&hIcon);
        pair<wstring, HICON> _pair = make_pair(trayList[i], hIcon);
        m_map_icons.insert(_pair);
    }
}

HICON WindowSysTray::getIconFromFile(const wchar_t* iconPath)
{
    auto iter = m_map_icons.find(wstring(iconPath));
    if (iter == m_map_icons.end()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        return iter->second; // ---Issue here---
    }
}

...
hIcon = getIconFromFile(L"tray.png");
if (hIcon)
{
    TrayIcon.SetIcon(hIcon);
}
...
```

When I invoke `getIconFromFile` function, it sometimes crashes while returning value at the end of the function:

> return iter->second;

I verified and make sure that I loaded Icon before by invoking `_loadIconFromFiles` function.

Does anyone know what is the possible root cause of this issue?

Comment: Maybe the instance of `WindowSysTray` is not valid?  Post a [mcve] to show how you created instances of this class.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code posted. How do you know it crashes when returning the value?

Comment: I'd ask a debugger.

Comment: Please, put the `HICON` into a smart pointer with custom deleter (`DestroyIcon()`).

Comment: @john It crashed and create a .dmp file. I also put some logs to test this.
Actually, it does not always crash.

Comment: @CuongHuynh Crashing on exit from a function is sometimes an indication of stack corruption, but there's no evidence of that in the posted code.

Comment: [mcve] that crashes or it didn't happen.

Comment: @CuongHuynh You only posted class code -- that is not enough.  We have no idea when, where, or how `WindowSysTray` instances are created.  If you are using an invalid `WindowSysTray` instance, then anything done within that invalid instance leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`m_map_icons.find()` could go wrong. This might be the case if `m_map_icons` is empty. You can start `WindowSysTray::getIconFromFile` with a check:
`if (m_map_icons.size() == 0) return 0;`